# Cannot convert from System.DateTime' to 'string' error on DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to save my DateTimePicker in my Master Data File (.MDF)

I tried searching the Internet for a solution but haven't been able to find anything.

Here is the section of code that is giving me the error:

```
private void cmdSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   dsSolomonNewTableAdapters.RegistrationTableAdapter ins = new       
     WindowsFormsApplication1.dsSolomonNewTableAdapters.RegistrationTableAdapter();
   ins.addStudent(this.dtoDOB.Value);
}
```

This throws an error:

> Cannot convert from System.DateTime' to 'string'

Any ideas?

Comment: What is happening when this code runs?

Comment: Quick response...What addStudent does?

Comment: What does the signature of the method addStudent look like?

Comment: @Reniuz the function of addStudent saves the date to my Master Data File where my coloumn name is Stud_DOB and its Data Type is Date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on that error message, this should fix it:

```
ins.addStudent(this.dtoDOB.Value.ToString());
```

That said, it seems like `addStudent` is adding a DOB, not a student.  Since I only have the code you posted to work with, I went with the `.ToString()`.

Edit: After seeing your last comment, it looks like `addStudent` should accept a `DateTime`, instead of `string`.  So in `RegistrationTableAdapter`, you might want to consider changing the method signature for `addStudent` to:

```
public/internal void addStudent(DateTime dob)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Again, I'm making a lot of assumptions here since you didn't post much code at all.